# SSRS: Need an expression for an average of a count of id numbers in column chart

Tags: reporting-services, column-chart

I've created a bar chart in SSRS with the count of ids per hour; but I need the average of the counted ids. Under the values, I'm doing a count on the ids and in the category groups, I have the column for hours (which are the 24 hrs in a day). I'm guessing I need an expression for this calculation but not sure how to do it. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please show some sample data (as text) , your current report output based on that sample data and what your expected result should look like. It's not clear (to me) what you are asking.